# How to allow FTP Clients to create new directories on an Apache FTP Server in Android?

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I am developing an Apache FTP Server for my Android App. I am able to connect to my FTP Server with FileZilla but I can't create new directories or upload datas on the Server and it seems that there doesn't exist a directory though I created one.

Here's my MainActivity.java file in which I declare the FTP Server and a BaseUser and set the WritePermission for this user:

```
package com.example.adminklui.server;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServer;
import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Authority;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PropertiesUserManagerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.SaltedPasswordEncryptor;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.WritePermission;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("home/server/users.properties"));
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());

    BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
    user.setName("username");
    user.setPassword("password");
    user.setHomeDirectory("/home/server/FTP/");

    List<Authority> authorityList = new ArrayList<Authority>();
    Authority authority = new WritePermission();
    authorityList.add(authority);

    user.setAuthorities(authorityList);

    try {
        userManager.save(user);
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

    serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);
    ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
    listenerFactory.setPort(2221);
    serverFactory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());

    FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer();
    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (FtpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my Manifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adminklui.server" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.adminklui.server"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'

}
}

dependencies {
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

When I want to create a new directory with FileZilla I always get the message in android studios logcat:

```
-org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter  - SENT: 550 No such directory.
```

Have I forgotten something or does the FTP Client not have the permission to create directories or upload files and why exists no directory on the FTP Server?

Thanks and I am looking forward to your responses

F. Klui

Comment: This is very unclear. Where are you trying to create a directory?. Please name full path.

Comment: When I connect to the FTP Server FileZilla tells me that I am in directory "\". When I want to create a new folder in this "\" directory FileZilla tells me I am not allowed to create it though I gave the user the permission to do so. Neither I can see the directory "home/server/FTP/" I created in the MainActivity.java class.

Comment: You did not create a directory in your main acfivity. You only used a statement user.setHomeDirectory("/home/server/FTP/"); Is that what you are referring at? That path does not exist on an Android device. And now you speak about "home/server/FTP/" which is a relative path.

Comment: Did you start with listing the files in /? That is much simpler. Just put some files in it your self first.